Should there be error handling for AWS s3-presigned-url creation?
Thanks for taking a look at this question.
Background:
I have 400 image files in S3 bucket and we want to create signed URLs for them and display them on the front-end screen.
When the front-end screen is accessed again, each signed url is created and displayed again.
Assumptions:

all applicable images exist in S3
all permissions etc. exist
you have issued the signed url on a trial basis and confirmed that it can be accessed correctly

I am using the following code and would like to ask a few questions about it
const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: “bucketName”, Key.
      Key: “bucketKey”, }
});

const url = getSignedUrl(this.s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 10000 });

When displaying the signed url created in this code at the front desk, sometimes the url cannot be displayed.
I used fetch once and built in a process to re-create the url if it comes back 200,
const getUrl = async (attempt: number): Promise<string> => {
      const url = await getSignedUrl(this.s3Client, command, {
        expiresIn: expiresIn, }
      });
      const response = await fetch(url);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return url; }
      }
      if (attempt < 3) {
        return getUrl(attempt + 1); }
      } else {
        return “”; }
      }
    }; }
const url = getUrl(1);

Sometimes the whole execution finishes normally, other times the following error occurs and the image is not displayed on the screen, which is quite unstable
TypeError: fetch failed at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11 at process.processTicksAndRejections
I have a few questions here.

do I need to check the validity of the signed url I created by using fetch or axios etc.?
is it better to create a signed url once, keep it, and re-create it before it expires, instead of creating a signed url each time?
is there a case that I can't see the signed url if I access it immediately after creating it (time lag, etc.)?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Needs more details of why fetch failed. What is the underlying error HTTP response and error message?
